# Odd problem with jQuery .change() event

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following select element with an onchange event.

```
<select name="ftest" onchange="alert('test');">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

I later bind another event on all the select elements in the page using jQuery (1.4.4).

```
   $("SELECT").change(function(){
    _isDirty = true;
   });
```

The result is my alert showing up twice when I change the value of my select list.

Anyone has an idea why this is happening or have a way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are doing but it works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox and Safari (latest versions, Mac OS X 10.6): http://jsfiddle.net/HSdBf/1/. So I assume it is related to something else in your code. Maybe you are calling `$(something).change()` somewhere OR it is a IE problem (what a surprise).

Comment: Are you trying to say that the act of binding the handler with jQuery cause the inline handler to be called twice?

Comment: Yes, the problem appears when I bind the handler with jQuery and yes, I am using IE8.

Comment: Why are you using the jQuery library AND writing inline javascript? You need to **never** write javascript in-line ever *ever* **ever** again. Put everything into the <script> section, not attributes of HTML elements. Article: http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-

Comment: I know...this is old code and I don't really have a choice. I guess I'll just drop jQuery and do the work like old times. :)

Comment: It works just fine in IE8 for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug with IE and jQuery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6593), due to the way they simulate bubbling for `change` in IE.  Unfortunately, there isn't a clean work-around at the moment, besides removing the inline `onchange` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that jQuery adds handlers, not replaces them. So for the above, you'd get one for your onchange attribute in the SELECT element, and another for the addition that jQuery makes.